# React Native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params') is the error code, but I dont know how to fix it...

```
Screen1:

function Screen1({ navigation }) {

  return (

between return and onPress are some components

   onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
                  title: "Beispiel Titel",
                  author: "Beispiel Author",
                  genre: "Beispiel Genre",
                })
```

Screen2:

```
function BookDetailScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { title, author, genre } = route.params;
```

Can anyone help? Thanks! :)

I want to give the params from Screen 1 to Screen 2

Comment: Have you tried `const { ... } = route?.params`?

Comment: I don't know why, but this worked, thanks Abe! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes react-navigation hasn't populated the `route` object on the first render. For this reason, it's best to destructure it with null checks or defaults, i.e.

```js
const { title, author, genre } = route?.params;
```

Or

```js
const { params } = route || { title: 'default title', author: 'default author' }; // etc
```